# Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've viewed a lot of posts with similar errors, but they don't work for me.
Here is how my code looks like:

```php
<form action="language" method="post">
        <select name="locale">
                <option value="en"{{ App::getLocale() == 'en' ? ' selected' : '' }}>English</option>
                <option value="de"{{ App::getLocale() == 'de' ? ' selected' : '' }}>German</option>
        </select>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I'm running my code I get this error:

> Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("punctuation" expected with value ",") in "/....." at line 66."

Maybe somebody has had this problem and solved it?
Thank You!

Comment: To have it clear, which one of those is the line 66?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you are using Twig (maybe?). Try switching `{{` and `}}` to `{%` and `%}`. OR... another way to try would be to replace the `::` with just `.` for example `{{ App.getLocale() == 'en' ...` ... hopefully one of those changes will work.

Idea #1:

```
<form action="language" method="post">
    <select name="locale">
            <option value="en"{% App::getLocale() == 'en' ? ' selected' : '' %}>English</option>
            <option value="de"{% App::getLocale() == 'de' ? ' selected' : '' %}>German</option>
    </select>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Idea #2:

```
<form action="language" method="post">
<select name="locale">
        <option value="en"{{ App.getLocale() == 'en' ? ' selected' : '' }}>English</option>
        <option value="de"{{ App.getLocale() == 'de' ? ' selected' : '' }}>German</option>
</select>
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```